# How do I acess the value of the last parameter of a function, given that the first two parameters are dynamic arrays?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, calling-convention, att

The function in C is

```
void f(int* out, int* in, int nbElements){
    // do stuff
}
```

Since `int nbElements` is the first to be pushed on the stack and `in` and `out` have variable sizes, how can I access the value of `nbElements`?
As far as I understand, the stack looks something like this:

```
          esp
          ebp
     return address         # -4(%ebp) 
1st element of int* out     # -8(%ebp)
1st element of int* in      # (%ebp - 8 - 4*nbElements)
      nbElements            # not sure how I can access the value of this
```

So how can I access the value of `nbElements` without knowing its address?

Comment: Your pointers have variable sizes?  I mean, surely, this is not a case where size matters? :)

Comment: yeah nevermind I think I confused the stack with the heap... so nbElements is at -16(%ebp) right?

Comment: `in` and `out` do *not* have variable sizes.  They are pointers, so each is 4 bytes, period.  The size of the array that they point to is variable, but that array is not passed on the stack and so the stack layout is not affected by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack frame is somewhat different.

The *caller* does *not* set up `%ebp`. That is up to the *called* function, *if* it choses to use `%ebp` at all.

Notice that in your function below, it does *not* use `%ebp` at all. All references to arguments are relative to the stack pointer (`%esp`).

This gives the stack frame:

```
1000: nbElements
0FFE: in
0FFC: out
0FFA: return address
0FF6: <---------------------- %esp points here
```

So, as below to access `nbElements`, you want `12(%esp)`

If *your* function sets up `%ebp`, the offsets will change by approx. 4:

```
    .text
    .globl  f
f:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,%ebp

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, outsave

    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, insave

    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, cntsave

    pop     %ebp
    ret
```

---

Here is something similar to your function:

```
int *outsave;
int *insave;
int cntsave;

void
f(int *out, int *in, int nbElements)
{

    // do stuff
    outsave = out;
    insave = in;
    cntsave = nbElements;
}
```

This is the assembly output:

```
    .text
    .globl  f
f:
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, outsave

    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, insave

    movl    12(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, cntsave

    ret
```

---

This is a sample caller of `f`:

```
void
f(int *out, int *in, int nbElements);

int outbuf[100];
int inbuf[100];
int bufcnt;

void
g(void)
{

    f(outbuf,inbuf,bufcnt);
}
```

This is the assembly for that:

```
    .text
    .globl  g
g:
    subl    $16, %esp

    pushl   bufcnt
    pushl   $inbuf
    pushl   $outbuf

    call    f
    addl    $28, %esp

    ret
```

Answer (score 5):

No, the array contents are not copied, only their addresses, so instead the stack will look like (assuming right-to-left calling convention, and addresses presented from high to low):

```
nbElements
in
out
return-address
(locals...)
```

The parameters each have a fixed address compared to each other (examine the code from a C call to such a function in order to confirm this). The last parameter will be at ebp+12 (assuming you have done a push ebp as part of a standard prologue.

Take a look at [functions and stack frames](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames), although you'll need to convert to at&t syntax.